# Trying to make an error message for my program

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to get an error message to display, but i'm getting some errors on my code. Below is the method for the message, the if else statement for the frame to display, and the method for the frame itself, as well as the error message. Thank you, and all help is appreciated!

method for the error.

```
public boolean errorMes(String s)
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    Integer.parseInt(s);
                                }
                                catch(NumberFormatExeception e)
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                catch(NullPointerExeception e)
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
```

action performed statement
                                        else

```
if(buttonCommand.equals("Calculate M1"))
        {
            GuiCalc CalcIeM1 = new GuiCalc();

            m2IeStr = m2InElas.getText();
            //m2IeNo = Double.parseDouble(m2IeStr);
            v1iIeStr = v1iInElas.getText();
            //v1iIeNo = Double.parseDouble(v1iIeStr);
            v2iIeStr = v2iInElas.getText();
            //v2iIeNo = Double.parseDouble(v2iIeStr);
            vfIeStr = vfInElas.getText();
            //vfIeNo = Double.parseDouble(vfIeStr);

            m2 = errorMes(m2IeStr);
            v1i = errorMes(v1iIeStr);
            v2i = errorMes(v2iIeStr);
            vf = errorMes(vfIeStr);

            if (m2 == true && v1i == true && v2i == true && vf == true)
            {

            m1IeNo = CalcIeM1.CalcInelasM1(m2IeNo, v1iIeNo, v2iIeNo, vfIeNo);
            m1IeStr = Double.toString(m1IeNo);

            JTable inelasTableM1 = new JTable(inelasData,inelasTitles);
            JScrollPane inelasScrollPanelM1 = new JScrollPane(inelasTableM1);
            inelasTableM1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            inelasTableM1.setBackground(Color.RED);
            inelasticFrame.add(inelasScrollPanelM1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }

            else{
                m1InElas.setText("");
                m2InElas.setText("");
                v1iInElas.setText("");
                v2iInElas.setText("");
                vfInElas.setText("");

            setError();
            }

            inelasticFrame.validate();
            inelasticFrame.repaint();
            System.out.println("M1 pressed");
        }
```

frame method

```
public void setError()
    {
        errorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        errorFrame.setBounds(200,200,200,200);
        errorFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        errorFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(elasColor);

        errorHomeButton.addActionListener(this);

        errorHomeButton.setToolTipText("Go Home");

        picturePanelError.add(errorIcon);

        textPanelErrorTitle.add(errorTitle);
        textPanelErrorMessage.add(errorMessage);
        buttonPanelError.add(errorHomeButton);

        errorFrame.add(textPanelErrorTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        errorFrame.add(textPanelErrorMessage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        errorFrame.add(buttonPanelError, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        errorFrame.add(picturePanelError, BorderLayout.EAST);

        errorFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

error message

```
GuiInter.java:300: error: cannot find symbol
        helpSelectButton.setToolTipText("Click for help");
        ^
  symbol:   variable helpSelectButton
  location: class GuiInter
GuiInter.java:909: error: cannot find symbol
                                catch(NumberFormatExeception e)
                                      ^
  symbol:   class NumberFormatExeception
  location: class GuiInter
GuiInter.java:913: error: cannot find symbol
                                catch(NullPointerExeception e)
                                      ^
  symbol:   class NullPointerExeception
  location: class GuiInter
3 errors
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:Chapter 15 paulnelson$
```

Comment: `errorMes` is missing a `return` statement (for the case where everything is OK)

Comment: im able to compile my program now(Thank you!) but I am getting a new error message once I try to launch the Frame.HERE IT IS                  
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
 at GuiInter.<init>(GuiInter.java:6)
 at GuiInter.main(GuiInter.java:939)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you don't know how to spell `Exception`.